# Why is my array only storing one item and replacing the old item with the new one?

Tags: reactjs, arrays, state, immutability

I have a checklist component on a React form. When an item is checked, I want to immutably add it to checkboxVal state array, when unchecked, I want to remove it. Currently, when I check a new value, it replaces the old value in the array, and there is only ever one value stored in the array. Here is the component:

```
function Checkbox({id, name, value, children, placeholder}) {
    const [checked, setChecked] = useState(false);
    const [checkboxVal, setCheckboxVal] = useState([]);
    
   
     const displayOtherTextareaInput = (e) => {
      setChecked(e.target.checked)
    }   
    
    const handleCheck = (e) => {
    let updatedCheckboxVal = [...checkboxVal, e.target.value];
    if(checkboxVal.includes(e.target.value)){
      updatedCheckboxVal = updatedCheckboxVal.filter(item => item !== e.target.value)
    }
    setCheckboxVal(updatedCheckboxVal)
  };

    const handleChange = (e) => {
      displayOtherTextareaInput(e);
      handleCheck(e);
    }

    return ( <>
        <CheckboxContainer>
            <Input type="checkbox" id={id} name={name} value={value} onChange={e => handleChange(e)}/>
            <Label for={id}>
                {children}
            </Label>
        </CheckboxContainer>  
        {id === 'other' && checked &&
                    <Textarea placeholder={placeholder} name={name}></Textarea>
            }
  </>)
}
```

Comment: As I know. the checkbox only have 2 value. You filter remove when it exist mean it only can have 1 value

Comment: I don't understand. Why do you need an array again?

Comment: @technophyle because I want to store an array of checked items which will then be sent to an email address via emailJS.